# Unexpected token in conditional rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to make the following code work but I'm getting a syntax error after the `displayPosts(posts);` call: `Unexpected token, expected "{"`

```
{hasPostsResolved && posts?.length > 0 &&
    displayPosts(posts);
    <input type="button" className="wp-element-button" value="Load More" />
}
```

For completeness:

```
const { posts, hasPostsResolved } = useSelect(select => {
    const query = {
        order: 'desc',
        orderby: 'date',
        status: 'publish',
        categories: category ? category : [],
        per_page: number
    };
    return {
        posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'post', query),
        hasPostsResolved: select('core').hasFinishedResolution('getEntityRecords', ['postType', 'post', query]),
    }
}, [category, number]);

const displayPosts = (posts) => {
    return (
        posts.map((post, index) => {
            return (
                <article id={`post-${post.id}`} key={index}>
                    <h2>
                        {
                            post.title.rendered ?
                            decodeEntities(post.title.rendered) :
                            __('(no title)')
                        }
                    </h2>
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }} />
                </article>
            )
        })
    )
};
```

Can someone tell what's wrong with my code? I can't make it work for the life of me.

Comment: `&&` except just a single thing to assign, not multiple

Comment: what is `displayPosts`? I don't want to answer your question until I know what it is because I might end up leading you astray. I'm hoping that it is essentially a component

Comment: @Zachiah I added the `displayPosts` function. It returns JSX code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant the following? I’m assuming that `displayPosts` is a function that returns JSX.

```js
{hasPostsResolved && posts?.length > 0 &&
    <>
        {displayPosts(posts)}
        <input type="button" class="wp-element-button" value="Load More" />
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Guillaume Brunerie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76663091/10892722) is 100% correct and is what I was going to answer however I did want to mention that there is no reason for `displayPosts` to not be a component. I would update the code like this:

```js
const DisplayPosts = ({posts}) => {
    return (
        // ...
    )
};

{hasPostsResolved && posts?.length > 0 &&
    <>
        <DisplayPosts posts={posts} />
        <input type="button" class="wp-element-button" value="Load More" />
    </>
}
```

I apologize for making essentially a duplicate answer but this was just a bit long for a comment.